# heroku unable to host nodejs error shows unable to recognise parcel

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, parceljs

**Error log of Heroku platform**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7acXY.png)
I tried to deploy app on Heroku sever but was unable to do due to some error

I tried to make Proc file and also edit the start point still it is unable to recognize parcel and also showing it has extra logging output

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps that are mentioned below:

1. make .env file
   and make PARCEL_WORKER=value(1,2,etc... depending on your parcel used)
2. the second step is splitting frontend and backend of the parcel as backend is generating some output and also frontend therefore 2 output are there which heroku is not able to  show so split them and make one sever and it will show only one output on both the server